# Do antidepressants reduce displays of anger prevalent in those diagnosed with ADHD?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, adhd, aggression

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder) and [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/add-adhd/adhd-anger-management-directory) , difficulties in managing anger are more prevalent in children with ADHD.

Why are antidepressants used in treating symptoms of ADHD?

Is this due to a relationship between aggression (specifically, the display of "angry" affect) and the administration of antidepressant drugs? Is this relationship well-studied?